# Alternative for recursive expressions in DataColumn

Tags: recursion, ado.net, dataset, calculated-columns

In my DataSet (which is persisted as XML), I have an `Area` table with three columns: `ID`, `Name`, and `ParentId`. `ParentId` is a foreign key that refers back to `ID`, effectively creating a hierarchy of Areas.

I want to maintain the *full path* of each Area in a new column called `Path`, whose value can be defined recursively as

```
             { area.Name                      ; if ParentId is null
area.Path := {
             { Parent.Path + "\" + area.Name  ; otherwise
```

I would have liked to implement this column as a computed column.
Unfortunately, when I try to set the `Expression` property to the following expression

```
iif(isnull(ParentId, 0) = 0, Name, Parent.Path + '\' + Name)
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression.

This seems to rule out a computed column. So what are the alternatives? I.e. how can I make sure that the `Path` column always contain a correct value that can be used in a data-bound UI?

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event handler to the datatable's row adding/changing (use events ending in ING as these fire before) events and check the value being added/altered has a closed path

Comment: This incremental approach is not going to work when the DataSet is read from XML, since the rows are not necessarily loaded in topological order (parents before children), but rather, all the rows are loaded into the table and then the constraints are enabled and checked.

Comment: So some post processing as part of the load, will be required(?)